# Watch OS3 accelerometer in the background ?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-3

Hey I am trying to have my watch app run the accelerometer in the background while the app is in the dock. I have been looking through documentation and it appears that there isn't any way to do this ?
Can anyone confirm ? 
The other way I was thinking, is there a way to get accelerometer history and use that instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make your app work long time in background except workout mode.
But accelerometer data is stored in M7 sensor for 3 days. You can ask sensor to start recording data (and it will record and store it without your app running) and schedule background refresh task to access this data.

Comment: Is there an example of this somewhere? and thanks for your response

Comment: never seen such example, but if you'll watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/218/ you'll get idea of background tasks, and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/713/ is about Motion in watchOS